# Should the neutral and ground bars in my panel be bonded?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

This is an older homes main panel. Question: I believe neutrals and grounds can not be on the same lug but can they be on the same bar? In addition, should i add a bonding screw on the top right?
Thanks!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo that clearly shows the label on the left side of the inside of the box?

Comment: Hello! Yes, I have posted better photos and I moved the grounds/neutrals. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Since this is a *main* panel, neutral and ground can go on the same bar

The reason why you see neutrals and grounds commingled here is because when wiring a main panel, many electricians who wire mostly main panels (vs. wiring subpanels for the most part) find it quicker and simpler to simply slobber all the neutral and ground wires onto whatever bonded bar is handy.  They can get away with this because your main panel is the *one and only* point in your system where neutral and ground are allowed to meet -- they must be kept separate everywhere else.

So, you can simply sort out any spots where neutral and ground have been landed on the same hole, and call it good.

### As to that ground screw?

As to the apparently-missing ground screw -- I'd try a Square-D 4028345850K since this appears to be a 100/125A loadcenter.  If it doesn't fit into the empty hole on the top right, post back with clear photos of the label on the inside left of the loadcenter cabinet.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response to my questions. That information you provided will help me out! I do have a follow up question. so I can fully understand. 1) On the picture I uploaded, i would simply need to seperate the neutral/ground wire combination on the same lug (shown once the right bar and once on the left bar)  and make each wire on its own lug? 2) Does the bonding screw go into the top right slot (Red arrow pointing at it)?